# Parsing API response Data as a data frame in Python with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to parse data from an API call to ERP system.  I want to bring this data in as a data frame with Pandas so that I can work with the data.  Every attempt to parse it with either json_string / json_dumps or DataFrame.from_dict() is not working for me.

My raw data file looks like:

```
Type:        dict
String form: {0: [{'productID': 144194, 'name': 'XXXtentacion, ?,        LP', 'code': '1039907', 'code2': '1210672',  <...> Field4Title': 'Format Notes', 'extraField4ID': 0, 'extraField4Code': '', 'extraField4Name': ''}]}
    Length:      1
    Docstring:  
    dict() -> new empty dictionary
    dict(mapping) -> new dictionary initialized from a mapping object's
        (key, value) pairs
    dict(iterable) -> new dictionary initialized as if via:
        d = {}
        for k, v in iterable:
            d[k] = v
    dict(**kwargs) -> new dictionary initialized with the name=value pairs
        in the keyword argument list.  For example:  dict(one=1, two=2)
```

The closest I get is calling:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

which returns:

```
                                                    0
0   {'productID': 144194, 'name': 'XXXtentacion, ?...
1   {'productID': 131605, 'name': 'Sufjan Stevens ...
2   {'productID': 143699, 'name': 'Sufjan Stevens ...
3   {'productID': 134277, 'name': 'Sufjan Stevens ...
4   {'productID': 135151, 'name': 'Sufjan Stevens ...
5   {'productID': 145844, 'name': 'Spearhead, Home...
```

but what I want is for the keys to be column headers (i.e. 'productID' should be 1st column header.

I'm just starting out with Python so any help is greatly appreciated.  I've looked around on similar topics and can't seem to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is structured as Dict(key1: List(Dict(...)), key2: ...)

Try

```
data = {d:data[d][0] for d in data}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  This has returned the first record with the keys as row indexes.  How would I edit this so that it would return the keys as column headers instead (flip the index)?

Comment: If you want to transpose a dataframe (convert rows to columns) add a `.T` at the end